# Subtract Count in Power BI

Tags: graph, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI Desktop

I am trying to reprent the data of access to the system we have

the access to the system can be either active active, deleted or blocked

if the access is blocked that means deleted by default

```
ID  Access Date User ID Blocked Deleted
1   01-Feb-18   18372   Yes     Yes
2   03-Feb-18   28360   No      No
3   28-Feb-18   72919   No      Yes
4   04-Mar-18   64220   Yes     Yes
5   25-Mar-18   17002   Yes     Yes
6   02-Apr-18   67298   Yes     Yes
7   10-Apr-18   77792   No      No
8   22-Apr-18   46201   No      No
9   05-May-18   83890   No      Yes
10  17-May-18   72615   Yes     Yes
```

I am trying to have a Donut Chart

[image]

for these info

- Active : Which is All records count - Deleted records count
- Deleted : Which is Deleted records count - Blocked records count
- Blocked : Which is just Blocked records count

I have built the query to retrieve all records, I just want to do the Donut chart

I can build the chart if it is just count of the a records, but to Subtract one count from the other, I dont know how to do that?

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the (...) to the right of your table in the fields sidebar on the right. Click "New column" and use this as your query:

```
Status = IF(Table2[Deleted]="Yes",IF(Table2[Blocked]="Yes","Blocked","Deleted"),"Active")
```

Replace Table2 in both occurances with your table name.

This field summarizes the three status options each entry can have.

Then drag your newly created Status field to the Legend filter for your donut chart.

[image]

[image]

[image]